# Как сделать переменную класса глобальной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим, у меня есть код, в котором мне нужно в двух различных функциях использовать одну и ту же переменную, полученную из другой функции класса. Код устроен по такому принципу:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def g(self):
        return self.num*5

    h = g() # та самая "глобальная" классовая переменная, о которой я говорю

    def minus(self):
        return h - 3 # где h == self.g()

    def plus(self):
        return h + 3 # где h == self.g()


def main():
    print(Test(5).minus())
    print(Test(5).plus())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вопрос, а вернее два вопроса.

1. Позволяет ли синтаксис языка Python совершать такие операции?
2. Сэкономит ли мне это время выполнения программы, при условии, что я
       захочу вызвать обе функции?

Comment: код выглядит сломанным. Не используйте сломанный код для спецификации задачи. Какое значение вы вкладываете в слово "глобальный" (в Питоне global имеет вполне определённое значение) Похоже на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044). Словами подробно опишите, почему вы думаете вам нужна "глобальная" переменная, какую проблему она у вас решает¶  Вопрос о микрооптимизации бессмысленно обсуждать без измерений (что требует рабочего кода).

Comment: Согласен, вопрос сформулирован не совсем корректно. Я не сразу понял, что если я два раза вызываю класс для разных методов, то нужда в этой переменной отпадает. Просто, читая мануалы я наткнулся на https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks где используется подобная конструкция

Comment: смысл комментария, чтобы вопрос улучшить, чтобы вам содержательный ответ дали, чтобы другим людям с похожей проблемой пригодилось бы решение¶ Информацию необходимую для ответа в сам вопрос помещайте, а нему комментарий. Нажмите кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 3):

```
from math import sqrt


class Test:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # Обявить переменную глобальной
        global global_change  # если закоментировать эту строку
        # то  функции hello_world произойдёт ошибка 
        global_change = "Hello world!"


    @property
    def my_function(self):
        return self.a * self.a + self.b * self.b

    def sqrt(self):
        return sqrt(self.my_function)

    def hello_world(self):
        print(global_change) # Использование глобальной переменной 
        # Вообще не рекомендуется пользовать глобальными переменными!


def main():
    print(Test(12, 18).sqrt())
    Test().hello_world()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Похоже, это то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

**Подумав я решил что правильный ответ на вопрос будет таким.**

```
class TestGlobalVariable:
    def __init__(self):
        global value
        value = "Hello world!"
        print(value)
        self.hello_user()

    def hello_user(self):
        value = "Hello user!"
        print(value)

test = TestGlobalVariable()
print(value)
```

Comment: На счёт экономии времени  надо пользоваться потоками и процессами